# Ruby on Rails – CanCan ability to only let an admin view published blog posts

Tags: authorization, cancan, ruby-on-rails-3.2

## tl;dr

I use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorization in a single-author blog. I want non-admin users to not be able to view unpublished posts. The following does not do the trick:

```rb
can :read, Post do |post|
  post.published_at && post.published_at <= Time.zone.now
end
```

Why doesn't it work, and what can I do to make it work?

Thanks. ;-)

## The long version

Hello World,

I have a single-user blogging application and use [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) for authorization purposes. I want administrators (`user.admin? # => true`) to be able to do whatever they wish with everything (they are administrators after all…). I also want regular users (both those who are logged in, but does not have the `admin` role, and those who are not logged in) to be able to view blog posts that have been published. I do not want them to see those that are not published.

Blog posts (of the model `Post`) each have an attribute called `published_at` (which is a `DateTime` and `nil` by default). Needless to say: when `published_at` is `nil`, the post is not published, otherwise it is published at the set date and time.

I have the following in my `Ability` class:

```rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize user
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, Post do |post|
        post.published_at && post.published_at <= Time.zone.now
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, this does not seem to work as I intend it to. I have read on the [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks) that this might not always work. However, I believe it should work in my case here, as I do have an instance of the `Post` model called `@post` in my `PostsController#show` action:

```rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource

  respond_to :html, :json

  # other actions omitted ...

  def show
    @post = Post.find params[:id]

    respond_with @post
  end

  # other actions omitted ...

end
```

Even with this code I am able to visit the blog post through the `show` action and view. I have also tried removing the `authorize_resource` call from the `PostsController`, realizing it might override some abilities or something, but it didn't help.

I have figured out a temporary solution, although I find it ugly and really want to utilize the CanCan abilities. My ugly temporary solution checks internally in the `PostsController#show` if the user has access to view the resource:

```rb
def show
  @post = Post.find params[:id]

  unless @post.published_at
    raise CanCan::AccessDenied unless current_user && current_user.admin?
  end

  respond_with @post
end
```

As I said, this works. But I don't really want to go with this solution, as I believe there's a better way of doing this as a CanCan ability.

I'd much appreciate an explanation of why my approach does not work as well as a good solution to the problem. Thanks in advance. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point where authorize_resource is being called (before_filter) you don't have a post object to authorize.

Assuming CanCan 1.6 or later, try this..

In your Post model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, lambda { where('published_at IS NOT NULL AND published_at <= ?', Time.zone.now) }
  # the rest of your model code
end
```

In your Ability model

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize user
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, Post, Post.published do |post|
        post.published_at && post.published_at <= Time.zone.now
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In your controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource
  respond_to :html, :json

  # other actions omitted ...

  def show
    respond_with @post
  end
end
```